# How to split a string considering more than one blank spaces in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, split

I'm trying to get an array with the following output:

```
["", "7", "02156567848", "CORTIER EP. ENGERANT ROSE JOSE MARIE", "059 NOMBRE DE LA PERSONA ES DIFERENTE"]
```

But using next code the result is different, because split is considering any non word character to separate the strings.

```
a = "    7           02156567848        CORTIER EP. ENGERANT ROSE JOSE MARIE.       059 NOMBRE DE LA PERSONA ES DIFERENTE"
b = a.split(/\W\W+/)
p b
```

Output:

```
["", "7", "02156567848", "CORTIER EP", "ENGERANT ROSE JOSE MARIE", "059 NOMBRE DE LA PERSONA ES DIFERENTE"]
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split on `\s{2,}` -- two or more white-space characters.

```
a = "    7           02156567848        CORTIER EP. ENGERANT ROSE JOSE MARIE.       059 NOMBRE DE LA PERSONA ES DIFERENTE"
a.split(/\s{2,}/)

# => ["", "7", "02156567848", "CORTIER EP. ENGERANT ROSE JOSE MARIE.", "059 NOMBRE DE LA PERSONA ES DIFERENTE"]
```

[repl](https://repl.it/repls/ItchyBiodegradablePrintablecharacter)